# How to use \mathsf or \symsf in kpfonts

Tags: sans-serif, sansmathfonts

[image]

We know that [kpfonts](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/fonts/kpfonts-otf/doc/Kpfonts-OTF-Doc-English.pdf) has a sans-serif math font, but the `\mathsf` and `\symsf` seem to use the CM fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bold-style=ISO,sans-style=italic]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}

\begin{document}
    Hello world ball, 2022.
    \begin{equation}
        \mathsf{ABC}\symsf{ABC}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fonts are different, though it can be hard to tell with sans fonts. Compare:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\PassOptionsToPackage{sans-style=italic}{unicode-math}
\usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[version=LM]

\begin{document}

Kpfonts:

$\mathsf{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$

$\symsf{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$

Latin modern (default:

\mathversion{LM}
$\mathsf{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$

$\symsf{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I compared EGQSU in my MWE and confirmed that it uses Kpmath sans-serif fonts.